# motion with constant acceleration question!

Tags: orbital-motion, acceleration, velocity

Consider a motorboat maneuvering on the surface of a lake, 
Is it possible for the boat to have accelerated motion in the x axis and unaccelerated motion in y direction?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the boat to have accelerated motion in the x axis and unaccelerated motion in y direction?

Yes, it's perfectly possible. The following is *just one example* of such a situation.

[image: Boat on a lake.]

Firstly, motion in the $x$ and $y$-direction are independent of each other.

In order to have acceleration in the $x$-direction, the following condition (Newton) has to be fulfilled:

$$ma_x=F_{motor}-F_{drag},$$

with $m$ mass, $a_x$ acceleration, $F_{motor}$ the force provided by the boat's motor and $F_{drag}$ the drag force exerted by the water on the boat. As long as:

$$F_{motor}>F_{drag},$$

then $a_x>0$, so we have acceleration in the $x$-direction.

Now suppose a side wind is blowing, causing drift in the $y$-direction:

$$ma_y=F_{wind}-F_{drag,y}$$

As long as:

$$F_{wind}>F_{drag,y}$$

then $a_y>0$ and there will be acceleration in the $y$-direction and the boat will also acquire a sideways speed after some time $t$, say $v_y$.

Assume now that at that point $t$ the wind drops a little so that:

$$F_{wind}=F_{drag,y}$$

Now there are no net forces acting in the $y$-direction and Newton tell us the boat will continue to drift in the $y$-direction at $v_y$ but without $y$-acceleration. But it will also continue to accelerate in the $x$-direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but I think I get the gist of it.
But yes, if there's no resistive force, you can have unaccelerated motion in a direction perpendicular to the direction of acceleration without the accelerating force affecting its direction or magnitude since it does no work on it. ($W = FS cos \theta$)
The same phenomenon occurs during parabolic motion where the horizontal unaccelerated motion is not affected by the download acceleration of gravity(assuming there's no resistive force like air resistance which would affect the horizontal unaccelerated motion)